# Fitting row space in an array

Tags: arrays, fractions, vertical

I have a simple array and some fractions are lying in under \displaystyle. The problem is that they collide with the upper and lower \hline, i.e. they lack of horizontal space. I know there might be a cheap solution of specifying the height of each row, but I'd like the rows to be fitting the content by themselves and not some scratchy manoeuvre, how could I achieve that?

```
\[
\begin{array}{|*6{>{\displaystyle}c|}} \hline
\sup \frac{V^\mathrm{col}}{V^\mathrm{row}} & V^\mathrm{ni} & V^\mathrm{fi} & V^\mathrm{pub} & V^\mathrm{priv} & V^* \\ \hline
V^\mathrm{ni} & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
V^\mathrm{fi} & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
V^\mathrm{pub} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1^* & 1\\ \hline
V^\mathrm{priv} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1\\ \hline
V^* & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please provide a fully working minimal example to make it convenient for others to use your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main solutions:

- load the `makecell` package and use its `\setcellgapes{some length}\makegapedcells` command, which *adds* a fixed amount of vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in a table (somewhat like `extrarowheight`, but also at the bottom);
- load the `cellspace` package, which lets you define  *minimal* paddings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, mathtools}
    \usepackage{makecell} 
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{array}{|*{6}{>{$\displaystyle}Sc<{$}|}} \hline
    \sup \frac{V^\mathrm{col}}{V^\mathrm{row}} & V^\mathrm{ni} & V^\mathrm{fi} & V^\mathrm{pub} & V^\mathrm{priv} & V^* \\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{ni} & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{fi} & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{pub} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1^* & 1\\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{priv} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1\\ \hline
    V^* & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1\\ \hline
    \end{array}
    \]
    \bigskip

    \[
    \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{array}{|*{6}{>{\displaystyle}c|}} \hline
    \sup \frac{V^\mathrm{col}}{V^\mathrm{row}} & V^\mathrm{ni} & V^\mathrm{fi} & V^\mathrm{pub} & V^\mathrm{priv} & V^* \\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{ni} & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{fi} & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{pub} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1^* & 1\\ \hline
    V^\mathrm{priv} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1\\ \hline
    V^* & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1\\ \hline
    \end{array}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I used the first option (the makecell package) and it does do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without additional packages, you could modify your array with `\setlength\extrarowheight{...}` and, at the end of every row, `[...]`, with `...` representing a dimension you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}
\begin{array}{|*6{>{\displaystyle}c|}} \hline
\sup \frac{V^\mathrm{col}}{V^\mathrm{row}} & V^\mathrm{ni} & V^\mathrm{fi} & V^\mathrm{pub} & V^\mathrm{priv} & V^* \\[10pt] \hline
V^\mathrm{ni} & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1 & 1\\[10pt] \hline
V^\mathrm{fi} & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\[10pt] \hline
V^\mathrm{pub} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1^* & 1\\[10pt] \hline
V^\mathrm{priv} & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & 1\\[10pt] \hline
V^* & \infty & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1\\[10pt] \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]